# How to obtain `@geogebra/math-apps` module?

Tags: geogebra

At https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Apps_API#Obtaining_the_API_Object_as_a_module:_The_ES6_way, it says

> You can use math-apps module now to inject the applet the ES6 way too

and then in the example code it shows

```
import {mathApps} from '@geogebra/math-apps';
```

But how can one find this `@geogebra/math-apps` module? It does not seem to be on NPM...